# LDA Results Errors

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, lda, topic-modeling, gensim

So, I am relatively new using Gensim and LDA in general. The problem right now is that when I run LDA on my corpus, the topics' tokens' weights are all 0:

2015-06-15 12:21:12,439 : INFO : topic diff=0.082235, rho=0.250000

2015-06-15 12:21:12,454 : **INFO : topic #0** (0.100): 0.000*sundayes + 0.000*nowe + 0.000*easter + 0.000*iniunctions + 0.000*eyther + 0.000*christ, + 0.000*authoritie + 0.000*sir + 0.000*saint + 0.000*thinge

2015-06-15 12:21:12,468 : **INFO : topic #1** (0.100): 0.000*eu'n + 0.000*ioseph + 0.000*pharohs + 0.000*pharoh + 0.000*iosephs + 0.000*lo! + 0.000*egypts + 0.000*iacob + 0.000*ioseph, + 0.000*beniamin

2015-06-15 12:21:12,482 : **INFO : topic #2** (0.100): 0.000*agreeable + 0.000*creede, + 0.000*fourme + 0.000*conteined + 0.000*apostolike, + 0.000*vicars, + 0.000*sacrament + 0.000*contrarywise + 0.000*parsons, + 0.000*propitiatorie

2015-06-15 12:21:12,495 : **INFO : topic #3** (0.100): 0.000*yf + 0.000*suche + 0.000*lyke + 0.000*shoulde + 0.000*moste + 0.000*youre + 0.000*oure + 0.000*lyfe, + 0.000*anye + 0.000*thinges

2015-06-15 12:21:12,507 : **INFO : topic #4** (0.100): 0.000*heau'nly + 0.000*eu'n + 0.000*heau'n + 0.000*sweet + 0.000*peace + 0.000*eu'ry + 0.000*constance + 0.000*constant + 0.000*doth + 0.000*oh

2015-06-15 12:21:12,521 : **INFO : topic #5** (0.100): 0.000*eu'n + 0.000*ioseph + 0.000*pharohs + 0.000*pharoh + 0.000*vel + 0.000*iosephs + 0.000*heau'n + 0.000*lo! + 0.000*ac + 0.000*seu'n

2015-06-15 12:21:12,534 : **INFO : topic #6** (0.100): 0.000*thou + 0.000*would + 0.000*love + 0.000*king + 0.000*sir, + 0.000*doe + 0.000*thee + 0.000*1. + 0.000*never + 0.000*2.

2015-06-15 12:21:12,546 : **INFO : topic #7** (0.100): 0.000*quae + 0.000*vt + 0.000*qui + 0.000*ij + 0.000*non + 0.000*ad + 0.000*si + 0.000*vel + 0.000*atque + 0.000*cum

2015-06-15 12:21:12,558 : **INFO : topic #8** (0.100): 0.000*suspected + 0.000*supersticious + 0.000*squire + 0.000*parsons + 0.000*ordinarie + 0.000*vsed, + 0.000*english, + 0.000*fortnight + 0.000*squire, + 0.000*offenders

2015-06-15 12:21:12,572 : **INFO : topic #9** (0.100): 0.001*/ + 0.001*ile + 0.000*y^e + 0.000*che + 0.000*much + 0.000*tis + 0.000*could + 0.000*oh + 0.000*neuer + 0.000*heart

I have 307 documents and I'm running my LDA with the following code after removing the stopwords:

texts = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 3 ] for text in texts]

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
tfidf_corpus = tfidf[corpus]

lda = models.LdaModel(tfidf_corpus, id2word = dictionary, update_every=1, chunksize= 20, num_topics = 10, passes = 1)

lda[tfidf_corpus]

lda.print_topics(10)

I am not sure what is wrong but everytime I run this, the token weights are 0. What might be causing this and how could I correct this?

Comment: how big is your dataset?

Comment: I'm using a corpus of 307 documents

Comment: can you paste the documents on pastebin or somewhere?

Comment: I would but they're actually sensitive documents that I'm not allowed to share